# Need help for building state machine config

Tags: spring-statemachine

I was trying to build a config for the state diagram attached[image: State diagram].
Thr problem is I couldn't register entry actions to states in regions inside a fork.
ie for states S41, S41E , S42, S42E.

The config looks like below.

Builder builder  = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

```
    builder.configureConfiguration()
    .withConfiguration()
        .autoStartup(false).listener(listener()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor());

 builder.configureStates().withStates().initial("S1", ActionFactory.getAction("S1EntryAction"))
    .fork("FORK_STATE")
    .join("JOIN_STATE")
    .state("S4")
    .state("S2", ActionFactory.getAction("S2EntryAction"), null)
    .state("S3", ActionFactory.getAction("S3EntryAction"), null)
    .state("S5", ActionFactory.getAction("S5EntryAction"), null)
    .state("S6", ActionFactory.getAction("S6EntryAction"), null)
    .state("S7", ActionFactory.getAction("S7EntryAction"), null)
    .and().withStates().parent("S4").initial("S41").end("S41E")
    .and().withStates().parent("S4").initial("S42").end("S42E");

    builder.configureTransitions()
        .withExternal().source("S1").target("S2")
        .and().withExternal().source("S2").target("S3")
        .and().withExternal().source("S3").target("FORK_STATE")
        .and().withFork().source("FORK_STATE").target("S4")
        .and().withExternal().source("S41").target("S41E")
        .and().withExternal().source("S42").target("S42E")
        .and().withJoin().source("S4").target("JOIN_STATE")
        .and().withExternal().source("JOIN_STATE").target("S5")
        .and().withExternal().source("S5").target("S6")
        .and().withExternal().source("S6").target("S7");

return builder.build();
```

One more Help.
In the above state machine config,each states has nested state machines.

S1 is having step0 and step1. Both are orthogonal
step0  is having states task1 and task 2
step1  is having states task3 and task 4
step0 is supposed to be completed when the parallel regions task1 and task2 finishes its exexution.
step1 is supposed to be completed when the parallel regions task3 and task4 finishes its exexution.
In fact  all the four states task1,task2,task3,task4 should execute parallely

S1 is complete if step0 and step2 is completed.

transitions from S1 to S2 will happen only after completing all the parallel states
ie (step0(task1 & task 2) and step2 (task3 and task4))

Also please note that S1 is the initial state of of my configuration.

I've updated the  the states configuration like below

```
.and().withStates().parent("S1")
            .initial("Step0")
                .and().withStates().parent("Step0")
                    .initial("task1", dummyAction1())
                .and().withStates().parent("Step0")
                    .initial("task2", dummyAction2())

.and().withStates().parent("S1")
            .initial("Step1")
                .and().withStates().parent("Step1")
                    .initial("task3", dummyAction3())
                .and().withStates().parent("Step1")
                    .initial("task4", dummyAction4())

.and().withStates().parent("S2")
            .initial("Step01")
                .and().withStates().parent("Step01")
                    .initial("task5", dummyAction3())
                .and().withStates().parent("Step01")

                    .initial("task6", dummyAction4())

.and().withStates().parent("S2")
            .initial("Step11")
                .and().withStates().parent("Step11")
                    .initial("task7", dummyAction3())
                .and().withStates().parent("Step11")
                    .initial("task8", dummyAction4())
```

How can I configure the transition from S1 to S2? (S1 is the initial state and S1to S2 should happen after completing all the parallel tasks in S1(ie. task1, task2, task3, task4).

Comment: Before I look this any further, did you try to do define action for `S41` with `.initial("S41").state("S41",null,null)` or with possible `.state("S41",null,null)` in a parent level? Also a lot of fixes has been done in 1.1.x which goes GA next week.

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Comment: I've updated the question. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Your question kinda got a little messy when you modified it but I kinda quickly tested something using uml(as it's easier and quicker to craft something together).

I pushed this into github [ssm-example1](https://github.com/jvalkeal/randomstuff/tree/master/ssm-sample1). Is a statechart there something you are trying to chase here?

When you run it you get order of state entrys and joins should handle that flow is `synchronized`. To execute something in-between `S1` and `S2` it might be easier to add additional state in a middle and execute stuff there. Might be handy to be able to add action to outgoing vertex from JOIN(s) but I'm not sure if it is legal and probably doesn't work with current ssm version(1.1.0.RELEASE).

I'll need to try how it behaves with async executor as ssm defaults to sync executor. It tries to use joins(which should not get a callbacks in listeners which is a bug I need to fix).

Without an explicit forks(controlled entry), state entrys will, in theory, fallback to default entry logic.

I didn't yet add any actions but those would be normal state entry/exit actions. In your sample when you associated an action with `.initial()`, it is not a normal state entry. Action with `initial()` is basically an initial transition action which is executed with default entry logic(which in theory will not be executed if direct entry to non-initial state happens).

Comment: Thanks for that Quick reply with the example. We're trying to build the configuration using builder, by reading the state names, transitions from an external data source. So can you please help me in getting the same configuration of ssm-sample1 using StateMachineBuilder.(ie not using uml or papyrus).

Comment: Also if possible with forking transitions to all parent states having more than one regions